# Cluster with `agnes`: how get Cluster Membership

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I have a huge dataset and created the clusters with `agnes` as follows:

```
hc.res1 <- agnes(example, method = "complete")
plot(hc.res1, which.plots = 2, main = "Complete Linkage (agnes)")
```

[image]

I would like to separate the dataset into two clusters (one split). How can I do that with `agnes`? So I would like to get a list which looks like the following

```
| Datarow | Cluster |
| 1       | 1       |
| 2       | 2       |
| 3       | 1       |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `cutree` function to cut the tree into a number of k clusters. As no sample data were given, let's demonstrate this with a built-in data set `iris` that contains 3 groups:

```r
library(cluster)

example <- iris # sample data set from R
hc.res1 <- agnes(example, method = "complete")
plot(hc.res1, which.plots = 2, main = "Complete Linkage (agnes)")

# let's assume k=3 clusters, then cutree shows the groups
cutree(k=3, hc.res1)
```

The numbers returned by `cutree` correspond to the row numbers of the original data set.